# Replace specific characters in a string without using replace method in Java

Tags: java, replace, char, string-parsing

I'm not allowed to use the replace() method and I basically have to have a part of my program that does this:

-Ask the user to type in a sentence to be manipulated.
-Then ask the user to enter which character to be replaced (i.e. "e" from "hello").
-Then ask which character they would like to it to be replaced with.

After it does all of this, it will output to the screen the manipulated string.

EXAMPLE:

- console: Please input a string:
- user: Hi there
- console: please enter the character to be replaced:
- user: e
- console: please enter a character to replace it with:
- user: l
- console: the new string is: Hi thlrl

I basically am able to do this, using this code:

```
    int count = 1;
    char replaceAll = 'a';
    char newChar = 'b';
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the string to be manipulated");
    String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
        replaceAll = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter the new character");
        newChar = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("The new sentence is: ");

        for(int c = 0; c < sentence.length(); c++){
            if(sentence.charAt(c) == replaceAll)
                System.out.print(newChar);
            else
                System.out.print(sentence.charAt(c));
```

MAIN PROBLEM: The only problem is that this won't save the manipulated string as a new string. It will only print the letters in the correct order for output (it prints one character at a time, not one string). I need the manipulated string (i.e. Hi thlrl) to be saved as a new string so that I can do more manipulations afterwards to that new string.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a `char[]` as per your `sentence` size and then populate it in loop.

```
  char[] ch = new char[sentence.length()];

  for(int c = 0; c < sentence.length(); c++)
   {
        if(sentence.charAt(c) == replaceAll)
        {
            System.out.print(newChar);
            ch[c]=newChar;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(sentence.charAt(c));
            ch[c]=sentence.charAt(c);
         }
     }
```

---

Other possible solution is, you could create `char[]` using `toCharArray()`

```
  char[] ch = sentence.toCharArray();

  for(int c = 0; c < sentence.length(); c++)
   {
        if(sentence.charAt(c) == replaceAll)
        {
            ch[c]=newChar;
        }
   }
```

And, create `String` using `char[]`.

```
  String mystring = new String(ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is Stringbuffer/StringBuilder then more simple is to using setCharAt

```
   StringBuilder sentenceStr = new StringBuilder(sentence); 
   sentenceStr.setCharAt(c, newChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to cut the string into pieces, on every occurrence of the character you wish to replace, then `join` to put it back together.  For example,

```
String.join("l", "Hello there".split("e", -1));
```

evaluates to `"Hllllo thlrl"`.

Note that the -1 is important - it stops the final element from being discarded if it's the one you're trying to split on.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize an empty string and as you loop across your sentence string, you can build up the new empty string like this:

```
String result = "";
for(int c = 0; c < sentence.length(); c++) {
    if(sentence.charAt(c) == replaceAll) {
        result += newChar;
    } else {
       result += sentence.charAt(c);
    }
 }
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

/* char 'o' replace with char 'd' without replace function */

```
    String oldString = "welcome mojo";

    String[] StringArray = oldString.split("");

    String newString = "";

    int count = StringArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        if (StringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {

            StringArray[i] = "d";
        }

        newString = newString + StringArray[i];

    }
    System.out.println(newString);
```